# Get only one related object from Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here are stripped down versions of the models I'm dealing with:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    contact_no = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)

class ContactRole(models.Model):
    contact_no = models.ForeignKey(Contact, primary_key=True, db_column='contact_no')
    role_code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=16)
    role_scope_code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=16)
```

Contacts can and almost always do have many ContactRoles.

**I want a list of Contacts where the role_scope_code of the related ContactRole is 'foo'.** I know I can get this with:

```
Contact.objects.filter(contactrole__role_scope_code='foo')
```

**What I *also* want, is for each Contact in the queryset to have a single .contactrole property. It would be the ContactRole with the role_scope_code of 'foo'.** Instead I'm getting a set of all ContactRoles that match on contact_no, so that to get to properties of the ContactRole I have to do something like this:

```
contacts = Contact.objects.filter(contactrole__role_scope_code='foo')
for contact in contacts:
    print contact.contactrole_set.filter(role_scope_code='foo')[0].role_code
```

I have to filter on role_scope_code twice! That doesn't seem DRY at all. What I'm looking for is a query that will allow me to have a set that works like this:

```
contacts = Contact.objects.filter(contactrole__role_scope_code='foo')
for contact in contacts:
    print contact.contactrole.role_code
```

**For the life of me I can't figure out how to tell Django to only return the related objects that match the filter I applied to the parent object.**

Answer (score 1):

A `OneToOneField` will solve this provided that a contact only have one contactrole. A `OneToOneField` gives you the api you are looking for. So instead of using a `ForeignKey` use a `OneToOneField`

Comment: While I think that this is true, the problem is that changing that relationship from ForeignKey to OneToOne incorrectly describes the relationship between those two tables. At some point down the road someone will likely need to see all the ContactRoles associated with a Contact.

Comment: Well the thing is that with a foreign key relationship there could be be two ContactRole objects with the role_scope_code='foo'. Thus being able to access that with `contact.contactrole.role_code` will never be possible as I understand it. If there is only one object you might get away with `contact.contactrole.get().role_code` but that will break when there are more than contactroles.

Comment: also if you want to change the name of `contactrole_set` to `contactroles` use `related_name='contactroles'` in the foreignkey